# How to return a list of related nodes for each node in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I would like to write a query for the graph below, which should return three lists, each list containing all persons working for the same person.

Given the graph below, the result should be this three lists:

- [Fritz]
- [Pepe]
- [Susy, Peter]

[image: Graph of work relationships]

I fail to write such query. My query returns all employes in one list.

The following statements create the graph model for the example I have given:

```
MATCH  (c:Example) DETACH DELETE c;

CREATE (p1:Parent:Example {id: 1, name: 'Andy', title: 'Developer'});
CREATE (p2:Parent:Example {id: 2, name: 'Lila', title: 'Developer'});
CREATE (p3:Parent:Example {id: 3, name: 'Lula', title: 'Developer'});

CREATE (c11:Child:Example {id: 11, name: 'Peter', title: 'Developer'});
CREATE (c12:Child:Example {id: 12, name: 'Susy', title: 'Developer'});

CREATE (c21:Child:Example {id: 21, name: 'Fritz', title: 'Developer'});

CREATE (c31:Child:Example {id: 31, name: 'Pepe', title: 'Developer'});

MATCH (p {id: 1}), (c {id: 11}) MERGE (p)<-[:WORKS_FOR]-(c);
MATCH (p {id: 1}), (c {id: 12}) MERGE (p)<-[:WORKS_FOR]-(c);
MATCH (p {id: 2}), (c {id: 21}) MERGE (p)<-[:WORKS_FOR]-(c);
MATCH (p {id: 3}), (c {id: 31}) MERGE (p)<-[:WORKS_FOR]-(c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's relatively straightforward with Cypher

```
MATCH (c)-[:WORKS_FOR]->(p)
RETURN p.name AS boss, collect(c.name) AS coWorkers
```

Result

```
╒══════╤════════════════╕
│"boss"│"coWorkers"     │
╞══════╪════════════════╡
│"Andy"│["Peter","Susy"]│
├──────┼────────────────┤
│"Lila"│["Fritz"]       │
├──────┼────────────────┤
│"Lula"│["Pepe"]        │
└──────┴────────────────┘
```

The trick is understanding aggregations https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#grouping-keys